# How to check for another running project on Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using eclipse IDE to run my spring boot project(the backend part) which uses the port 8080 on localhost. When i try to run my program it shuts down the program saying **port 8080 was already in use**. There isn't any other application that is using the port 8080 and there is no other console window because of which i cannot shut down the currently running application that is using port 8080. PFB the logs from the console window:

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)

2020-09-24 19:31:44.942  INFO 4092 --- [           main] c.library_management.lms.LmsApplication  : Starting LmsApplication on DESKTOP-GM2UUP2 with PID 4092 (D:\eclipse-workspace\lms\target\classes started by Electrical Engineer in D:\eclipse-workspace\lms)
2020-09-24 19:31:44.948  INFO 4092 --- [           main] c.library_management.lms.LmsApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-24 19:31:50.633  INFO 4092 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-09-24 19:31:51.947  INFO 4092 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1092ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-09-24 19:31:59.953  INFO 4092 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-24 19:32:00.358  INFO 4092 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-24 19:32:00.360  INFO 4092 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-09-24 19:32:01.666  INFO 4092 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-24 19:32:01.667  INFO 4092 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 16526 ms
2020-09-24 19:32:05.077  INFO 4092 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-24 19:32:06.080  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-24 19:32:06.793  WARN 4092 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-09-24 19:32:08.214  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2020-09-24 19:32:16.114  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-24 19:32:16.817  INFO 4092 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5477a1ca, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6794ac0b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@77d680e6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@33a3c44a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@222afc67, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5cb5bb88, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3a01773b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3ae9d1e2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5c1f6d57, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6014a9ba, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@65f2f9b0]
2020-09-24 19:32:21.739  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-24 19:32:26.793  WARN 4092 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException: Port 8080 is already in use
2020-09-24 19:32:26.862  INFO 4092 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-24 19:32:31.239  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-09-24 19:32:31.877  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-09-24 19:32:41.109  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-09-24 19:32:41.172  INFO 4092 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Exception in thread "task-2" 2020-09-24 19:32:41.202  INFO 4092 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-24 19:32:41.204  INFO 4092 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getProperties(SessionFactoryImpl.java:503)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.findDataSource(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2020-09-24 19:32:41.413  INFO 4092 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-09-24 19:32:41.418  INFO 4092 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-09-24 19:32:41.629  INFO 4092 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-09-24 19:32:41.652 ERROR 4092 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be because you might gave run the project first (so it occupied the port) and now you are trying to run it again without closing the last one.[Use this Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vTY8.png)

Comment: Use can see all running consoles here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not ambiguous, and that's not something that will occur "erroneously" (saying something is using the port when it's not actually in use).  The port doesn't have to be used by something you started from Eclipse. There is no question that something is already listening on that port. You just have to figure out what it is.  Alternatively, you could set up your application to run on a different port.

Comment: Yes when i checked, the same data was being delivered which this application delivered on the last run. So i figured i was foolish enough to close the Eclipse IDE before terminating the program. I had to restart my PC to make it work. Thanks anyways :)